# JavaScript: Quickly insert text into long textarea

Tags: javascript, firefox, textarea

I am playing around with creating an HTML-textarea based plain text editor to edit my scripts (using e.g. Mozilla Prism + a localhost install/ webserver). It works fine so far, but when I want to insert something at the cursor position, it gets slow in Firefox when there is a lot of text in the textarea (Chrome works fine). E.g. with 133k filled in the textarea it takes around 1 sec to perform inserting 4 spaces.

I already have and use elm.selectionStart and elm.selectionEnd. Based on these I then copy the text, manipulate it, and set the value back into the textarea -- perhaps that is what's causing the bottleneck (I'm using the similar approach [as answered on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849978/inserting-input-field-text-into-textarea-with-javascript) before). Ideally, I would probably like to have something like elm.selectedText = 'foobar' but can't find this...

It doesn't necessarily need to be crossbrowser...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article on codemirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/story.html), using designMode is faster than using a textarea, because you can edit parts of the content instead of editing the whole text in one go.

Answer (score 0):

There's an API that replaces the selected text: `textarea.setRangeText('text')`.

Here's a demo:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
textarea.addEventListener('click', () => {
  textarea.setRangeText('WOW');
});
```

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="40">Click anywhere or select any text in here. It will be replaced by WOW</textarea>
```

There's also `document.execCommand('insertText')` with `undo` support but it's not cross-browser. Try [insert-text-textarea](https://github.com/bfred-it/insert-text-textarea) for a cross-browser solution.